# Execute .ps1 file as parameter from a C# project

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

I am trying to execute a `.ps1` file from my C# console application. Using the code provided below you can see what I am trying to do:

```
public static void execitePs(string originalString)
{
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            // specify the script code to run.
            ps.AddScript(@"C:\PnP\test_script_json.ps1");

            // specify the parameters to pass into the script.
            ps.AddParameter("originalString", originalString);

            // execute the script and await the result.
            var pipelineObjects = ps.Invoke();
            // print the resulting pipeline objects to the console.


            foreach (dynamic item in pipelineObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);

            }
        }
}
```

Basically I am trying to supply the file path to the `AddScript` method as explained in the Microsoft example. This should call the script file and execute it. Here is the script file content:

```
param ($originalString)

$JSONString = @"
    $originalString
"@


Write-Output HEREEEEEEEE
$cusomObject = ConvertFrom-Json $JSONString

Write-Host $cusomObject.Name
```

The whole process is basically taking some JSON as parameter and printing the property `name`.

Even if the JSON is missing the property it should print the `HEREEEEEEEE` string to the console.

As a result I am not getting any output since the `pipelineObjects` Collection is empty after invoking the script.

Moreover, I have managed to execute it successfully using the following method:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", @"-File ""C:\PnP\test_script_json.ps1"" """ + originalString + "");
```

but using this is not so flexible.

***Any ideas how I can do the same using the `PowerShell` object?***

Any help/idea is appreciated!

Best regards, Dimitar

Comment: I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around launching a Powershell script to obtain a value from a JSON object _using C#_. Is there some deeper level to this that requires the additional complexity?

Comment: I am doing an automation process to deploy a SharePoint sites. The backend .NET but the automation process should be using PnP Powershell (special request). So the easiest way of passing the complex object from C# to Powershell in my eyes is a JSON. That is why such process is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this helper method.

```
private Process CreateAndStartProcess(string fileName, string arguments)
{
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
        FileName = fileName,
        WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0",
        Arguments = arguments,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = true
    };

    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = startInfo
    };

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    return process;
}
```

You can launch it via

```
var arguments = @"-File C:\PnP\test_script_json.ps1" + originalString;
var process = CreateAndStartProcess("powershell.exe", arguments);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the commands are returning a new Powershell-Instances so your changes are not actually applied

You need to either do:

```
ps
    .AddScript(@"C:\PnP\test_script_json.ps1")
    .AddParameter("originalString", originalString)
    .Invoke();
```

or

```
        // specify the script code to run.
        ps = ps.AddScript(@"C:\PnP\test_script_json.ps1");

        // specify the parameters to pass into the script.
        ps = ps.AddParameter("originalString", originalString);

        // execute the script and await the result.
        var pipelineObjects = ps.Invoke();
        // print the resulting pipeline objects to the console.
```

Comment: I have already tried that but it did not work. Thanks for the response!